# Copying a table with employee info from test database to production in Advanced Query Tool

Tags: oracle, advanced-query-tool

I am looking to copy a table with employee information from my company's test database, to the production database in Advanced Query Tool. The first thing i did was to export the table data in a csv file, then trying to import the same data into the test database, but i get an error saying: "Unable to create table" error during ExecDirect 37000(972)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00972: Identificator is too long"

Comment: What is this "Advanced Query Tool"?

Comment: http://querytool.com/

Comment: Are both of your databases Oracle? Open up your CSV file and check the header row (assuming there is one) and verify that there are no identifier names longer than 30 characters.

Comment: Both are Oracle yes, and if one of the databases is longer than 30 characters what do you suggest i do?

Comment: Is'n it easier to do the same with create table as select...? No tools needed.

Comment: Well how do i create table in another database connection? When i log in to the test database the table i need to copy to production database is there, but when i log in to the production database there is no table.